# How to check if item is the last element to fulfil a certain condition inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

let's say I have arbitrary data which looks like this

```
data= [{foo: bar},{foo: false},{foo:bar},{foo: false}];
```

and I am looping through that data using JQUERY. How do I check if an iteration is the last to fulfil a certain condition, for example;

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){


    if (value.foo===bar) {
        //do something
        // if this is the last which has a foo which is === bar then do something
    }

});
```

Comment: Don't use jQuery and just start from the end so the first match would be the last in a regular loop.

Comment: Can you please elaborate who the workflow should work ? Do you want to check the condition inside the loop or first check the last element and then do your work, or, or or... To just check the last element use `arr.slice(-1)[0] `

Comment: @Marc _"is the last to **fulfil a certain condition**"_

Comment: That dosnt answer my question

Comment: No, but it makes your last sentence irrelevant

Comment: Just compare `key === index.length - 1` and then do what you want or `value.foo===bar && key === index.length - 1`

Comment: @Marc , (value.foo===bar && key === index.length - 1) will not work because in the dummy dataset the key of the element  is actually index.length - 2, the question is how do we find that key given we only know that it is the last element that has foo==bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate a `map + filter` using `reduce` to do this:

```js
var data = [{foo : 'bar'}, {foo : false}, {foo : 'bar'}, {foo : false}];

var elems = data.reduce(function(filtered, obj, index) {
  if (obj.foo === 'bar') {
     filtered.push(index);
  }
  return filtered;
}, []);

var last_index = elems[elems.length - 1];

data.forEach((value, index) => {
  if (value.foo === 'bar') {
    //do something
    //if this is the last which has a foo which is === bar then do something
    if (index === last_index) {
      // do the thing
      console.log('last: ', value, index);
    }
  }
});
```

Or, you can work with `data` backwards, and use a boolean to detect whether you have seen the last element or not:

```js
var data = [{foo : 'bar'}, {foo : false}, {foo : 'bar'}, {foo : false}];

var last = true;

$.each(data.reverse(), function(key, value) {
  if (value.foo === 'bar') {
    //do something
    //if this is the last which has a foo which is === bar then do something
    if (last) {
      // do the thing
      console.log('last: ', value, data.length - key - 1);
      last = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is pretty clever, let me try this.

Comment: @AlvinMoyo That's not clever. That's overly complicated and iterates over the array _twice_ for the second option or _three_ times for the first option.

Comment: @Andreas, so far it's the only way I have seen that works, the solution is not taxing much on my application perfomance though, I thought it would because my real dataset is very very large. What I did to optimise is I "returned false" to break the first loop as soon as I grabbed the key. I saw in one of your comments saying not to use JQUERY, but won't we end up having to reiterate again, how best can we optimise. PS can you post your solution as an answer for future SO users.

Comment: @Andreas I have modified it to do `map + filter` in one go, using `reduce`. You have to iterate at least once to get the desired result if you want to iterate `data` forward.

Comment: @AlvinMoyo _"...to break the first loop as soon as I grabbed the key"_ - So you actually only want that one entry? Then why the loop at all? And why is this requirement not part of the question?

Comment: @AlvinMoyo _"can you post your solution as an answer"_ - I've [already done that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64501449/402037)

Comment: @Andreas The reason I didn't bother optimizing my solution using `data.reverse()` was because I thought the OP might want to iterate forward through the data, so I focused on the other solution. But now with this _"...to break the first loop as soon as I grabbed the key"_, I guess it makes this much more trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular `for` loop and iterate in reverse order over your collection so the first match would be the last match in original order

```js
let data = [{ foo: 'bar' }, { foo: false }, { foo: 'bar' }, { foo: false }];

for (let i = data.length - 1, found = false; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (!found && data[i].foo === 'bar') {
    console.log('"last" match at ', i);
    found = true;
  }
  
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store the last foo which is equal to bar in a variable and do operation on it outside the loop.

See below sample code

```
var lastFooEqBar= null;
$.each(data.reverse(), function(key, value) {
    if (value.foo === bar) {
        //do something
        //store in variable
        lastFooEqBar = value;
    }
});
if(null!=lastFooEqBar) {
  //do operation on last foo equals to bar
}
```